# Проблема с ф-цией для замены строк в двумерном массиве

Tags: c, строки, функции

Есть двумерный массив text, в котором необходимо поменять местами нечетные строки по кругу. Для этого объявлена ф-ция transformation1, но при вызове этой ф-ции одна из строчек располагается не на своем месте.

```
void Transformation1(char **text, int countofstr){
int i;
int mult;
char *p;
if (countofstr%2==0) mult=(countofstr-2);
else mult=(countofstr-1);
p=text[mult];
for (i=0; i<mult; i=i+2){
    text[i+2]=text[i];
}
text[0]=p;
}
```

Исходный тексте:

> abcd
>   def
>   ghk
>   rlh
>   fhk
>   eyc

Пример правильного выполнения ф-ции:

> fhk
>   def
>   abcd
>   rlh
>   ghk
>   eyc

Ф-ция transformation1 выполняется следующим образом:

> fhk
>   def
>   abcd
>   rlh
>   abcd(!!! неправильная строка !!!)
>   eyc

Comment: а как вы вызываете функцию, как массив передаёте?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На самом деле здесь помог бы отладчик. Рассмотрим цикл

`for (i=0; i<mult; i=i+2)
    text[i+2]=text[i];`

Здесь мы последовательно заносим 0->2 2->4 (а в 2 уже 0, помним же). и так далее. По факту мы все чётные элементы заменим на 1. И потом доставим последний.

Вот исправленный пример.

```
void Transformation1(char **text, int countofstr){
   char *p;
   int x = countofstr - 2 + (countofstr&1);
   p=text[x];
   for (int i=x; i>1; i-=2)
     text[i]=text[i-2];
   text[0]=p;
}
```

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, объяснить общий принцип для int x, почему именно такое присваивание? countofstr - общее кол-во строк в двумерном массиве text.

Comment: @UbiProvance не люблю `if` там где без него можно, можете использовать как у вас было, главное разверните `for` в порядок по убыванию.